# Android. How to Position Fragment in Layout

Tags: android, position, fragment, transparent

I have following Problem. I Added a fragment "a" Inside Activity "A". 
I did this in code with the transaction manager.
I added my fragment to the framelayout you can see in my xml. 
When i run the App it looks like this (see picture) 
Nothing in the fragment is clickable. Everything else, even under (or above in this case) is clickable.

When i add the fragment to the very outter relative layout of the display xml file everything works fine, then i cant positon the fragment in my layout though.

How can i change either set the fragment clickable, or position it right? 
Code is working fine.

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3574/qqe6exvk_jpg.htm

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".UserProfileActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/userProfileLayout" >



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="changeProfilePicture"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/update_picture" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/Line1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Picture"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Line1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Line1"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_RealnameInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Realname"
                android:text="@string/name_info" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_Realname"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/realname" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRealname"
                style="@style/buttonredblack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_Realname"
                android:onClick="changeRealname"
                android:text="@string/button_ok" /> 

             <RadioGroup
                 android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView_RealnameInfo"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingTop="35dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RadioButtonMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RadioButtonFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/female" />

            </RadioGroup>

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView_Your_Gender"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView_RealnameInfo"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:paddingTop="38dp"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:text="@string/your_gender" />

              <RadioGroup
                 android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView_RealnameInfo"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingTop="85dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RadioButtonLookingMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RadioButtonLookingFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/female" />

            </RadioGroup>

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView_Searching_Gender"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView_RealnameInfo"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:paddingTop="88dp"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:text="@string/searching_gender" />

              <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView_Searching_Radius"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Searching_Gender"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:paddingTop="25dp"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:text="@string/searching_radius" />

              <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonEditRadius"
                style="@style/buttonredblack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_Searching_Radius"
                android:onClick="openSearchRadiusFragment"
                android:text="@string/button_edit" /> 




        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the completed layout . textView_Picture and textView_Searching_Radius views are missing

Comment: okay I added all of the xml.

Comment: where do you want to position the fragment?

Comment: right underneath @+id/Line1. As shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that your FrameLayout and Scrollview are in same position (below Line1). since you have added Scrollview after FrameLayout , scrollview is handling the touch events.  You have to move your Framelayout below the scrollview . else if you want the framelayout on top of scrollview and handle the action, the best approach is remove the frame layout  and create a DialogFragment and set the fragment layout. you can show and hide the dialog whenever required.

Comment: is there really no other way where i can keep my existing fragment class as it is?

Comment: You need to just change your custom fragment extends to DialogFragment . see this link. Its very simple to do http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html